# How to add and retrieve arraylist of value in shared preference in android

Tags: android

How to add and retrieve arraylist of value in shared preference in android. Can you please give example for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [code](https://github.com/sudar/android-samples/blob/master/TaskManager/src/com/sudarmuthu/android/taskmanager/util/ObjectSerializer.java) from this [tutorial](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/2010/02/23/using-preference-api-in-android-applications.html)

& you are done!