# how to store top high score in shared preference

Tags: android

I want to store top 5 High score with username in shared preference.  So I need to store to value at the same time, user name and the value. But I found preference only allow one value with a key. 
So my question is how I can store top 5 values with username in a shared preference. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add and retrieve arraylist of value in shared preference in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283009/how-to-add-and-retrieve-arraylist-of-value-in-shared-preference-in-android)

Comment: @rokonoid: could you please share me the code, how to store top 5 High score with username

Comment: I think you can keep them into sqlite, very easy these days. Unfortunately  I don't have that code right now.

Comment: hey @rokonoid how did you get yours to work, i have the exact same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Option #1: Have two separate keys: `top name` and `top value`
- Option #2: Store value in parseable format and include both user name and value like `User/50`

Answer (score 2):

If you're struggling with shared preferences I'd recommend 
[this tutorial](http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-sharedpreferences/) - it covers everything you need to  know about Shared Preferences with a practical example.

Having said that, I my opinion I think you'd be better off using an SQLite database.
If you are interested in using a database 
[this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/28/get-started-developing-for-android-with-eclipse-reloaded/)  is a good read:

Answer (score 0):

You can store the high scores in shared preferences as a list. This might help you out -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876680/is-it-possible-to-add-an-array-or-object-to-sharedpreferences-on-android

Check out the first answer.